# How to shutdown an external process that was started?

Tags: elixir

I'm making an Elixir app (using `GenServer`) that spawns an external Node.js server on bootup and shuts it down on exit. I'm successfully able to start the Node.js server but I can't shut it down. I've currently tried using:

- [`Process.spawn/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Process.html#spawn/2) and [`Process.exit/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Process.html#exit/2)
- [`Port.open/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Port.html#open/2) and [`Port.close/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Port.html#close/1)
- and even the [`Porcelain`](https://github.com/alco/porcelain) package

So my question is, **how can I shut down an external process that I started in Elixir?**

---

[*Relevant Discussion*](https://elixirforum.com/t/start-nodejs-server-with-phoenix-app/1790)  on ElixirForum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after doing some research on [Unix Signals and Traps](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm) and going through many emails on the [Erlang Mailing List](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-March/050227.html) and discussions on the [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/start-nodejs-server-with-phoenix-app/1790), it turns out:

> When a process is exited (the port is closed) the spawned program / port
>   should get an `EOF` on its `STDIN`. This is the "standard" way for the process to detect when the port has been closed: an end-of-file on STDIN.

**The other program should handle `EOF` on `STDIN` and shutdown gracefully.** This should work for the majority of the programs, but in the case of my Node.js server, it didn't happen. So I had to manually handle this case in my app and exit:

```
process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  console.log("STDIN closed"); 
  process.exit(); 
});
```

---

I still think that there should be a way to force kill (i.e. either send `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` to) the external program from Elixir/Erlang.

Comment: The porcelain library with the additional goon executable is one way to handle this problem in the general case.

Comment: Can you elaborate w/ examples @FredtheMagicWonderDog? How can I send `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` with the `goon` driver?

Comment: The goon executable is essentially a wrapper that accepts messages from the Porcelain library to implement the standard signals ( and lot's of other nice things as well. )

Comment: See http://porcelain.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/index.html#Porcelain.Process.signal/2

Comment: I actually already tried that. Did not work. I used `Porcelain.Process.signal(proc, sig_id)` with signal ids for INT, QUIT and KILL

Comment: Did you have the goon driver installed? It won't work w/o that.

Comment: Oh I didn't. I'll try it with that.